# Command line arguments containing &&

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to run some Java code using the command prompt. The name of the file is also the name of the class containing the `main` method. Below are the steps I followed:

1. `javac <filename.java>`
2. `java <filename> <arguments>`

I am passing some arguments which contain `&&` as a part of the argument value, but the command prompt is not able to recognize it as just part of the argument value. Can someone please let me know how to escape this in the command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to surround a single argument with quotes `"`, and anything inside the quotes will be treated as a single argument value.

```
java MyFile "some&&argument" "some-other-argument" anArgWithoutQuotes
```

Comment: @WhoAmI You're welcome! Don't forget to mark it as accepted, so that others having similar issues can see that this question has a solution.